# Attach scroll event to div with body on() binding fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, binding, scroll

I'm having some trouble with the scroll event.

I'm trying to attach/bind the event to a specific div,
and I'm using `$('body').on()` to do it, due to the fact that 
the content is reloaded when sorting, so it will lose its binding.

This doesn't work, the event is not fired:

```
$('body').on('scroll', 'div.dxgvHSDC + div', function () {
}
```

This on the other hand works:

```
$('body').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', 'div.dxgvHSDC + div', function () {
}
```

And this as well:

```
$('div.dxgvHSDC + div').on('scroll', function () {
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can not add delegation to the `scroll` event. This event doesn't bubble up the DOM and therefore you can not delegate it to any element. You can find more information [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html):

> **The scroll event does not bubble up.**
>
> Although the event does not bubble, browsers fire a scroll event on both document and window when the user scrolls the entire page.

You will need to create the event handler inside the event which creates your scrolling element.

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/Um5ZT/1/

```
$('#link').click(function(){

    //dynamically created element
    $('body').append('<div class="demo"></div>');
        
    //dynamically added event
    $('.demo').on('scroll', function () {
        alert('scrolling');
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Found the same page yesterday. Readded listener at the end of the callback directly on the element instead.

Answer (score 15):

On modern browsers (IE>8), you can capture `scroll` event to e.g `document` level for dynamic element. As jQuery doesn't implement capturing phase, you have to use javascript `addEventListener()` method:

```
document.addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    function(event){
        var $elm = $(event.target);
        if( $elm.is('div.dxgvHSDC + div')){ // or any other filtering condition
            // do some stuff
            console.log('scrolling');
        }
    },
    true // Capture event
);
```

Comment: This is my preferred answer and should be the accepted answer.