# add scroll listener by id

Tags: reactjs, dom, listener

Hi i cannot add scroll listener by id, it works with `WINDOW` but doesnt work in custom scroll element.
Here is my code :

```
componentDidMount() {
    const scrollPanel = document.getElementById('scrollPanel');
    scrollPanel.addEventListener('scroll', this.listenToScroll);
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    const scrollPanel = document.getElementById('scrollPanel');
    scrollPanel.removeEventListener('scroll', this.listenToScroll);
  }

listenToScroll = () => {
    const { position } = this.state;
    const scrollPanel = document.getElementById('scrollPanel');
    const winScroll = scrollPanel.scrollTop;
    const height =
         scrollPanel.scrollHeight -
         scrollPanel.clientHeight;

    const scrolled = winScroll / height;
    console.log('scrolled', scrolled);
    this.setState({
      position: scrolled,
    });
```

When i try to check some value its never changes

Answer (score 0):

There must be an event handler inside the element which creates the scrolling element:
Here in your case, change the `componentDidMount()` to below:

```
componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener(
            "scroll",
            this.listenToScroll,
            true // Capture event
        );
    }
    listenToScroll = () => {
        //Your custom code
        alert("click triggered");
    };
```

I tried and it works

You might want to check this answer where I got the reference from :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30475606